# vcxproj does not build generated source code the first time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, vcxproj

I have a VS 2010 vcxproj that contains no source code. A PreBuildEvent calls a batch file that uses a third party tool to generate source code into my src\ directory. That works fine. The problem is that the first time the source code is generated (or after a clean), VisualStudio does not actually compile the generated source. On a subsequent build, it does compile. This is a problem for my CI build machine as well as annoying to developers. Is there any way to get VS to recognize those generated files?

Here's a snippet from my .vcxproj

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
    <Message>Generating from IDL </Message>
    <Command>genNAPIEMsgs.bat</Command>
  </PreBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ClInclude Include="src\*.h" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="src\*.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
</ImportGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <DDSGeneratedFiles Include="src\*.cpp" />
  <DDSGeneratedFiles Include="src\*.h" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterClean">
  <Message Text="AfterClean target: removing generated source code" />
  <Delete Files="@(DDSGeneratedFiles)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Where is the snippet for the pre-build event?

Comment: Google "msbuild delay evaluation" for decent looking hits.  If that doesn't pan out then use two projects.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it happens because of evaluation order in msbuild project.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx

Cpp files that are incorporated into compilation are defined as global items ClCompile. So they are evaluated before any target is executed. At the moment evaluation is started there is none generated cpp file so none of generated files is compiled.
You can modify ClCompile items by Returns attribute of target. But as far as I’m aware PreBuildEvent  target does not Returns anything.
So you can inject your own target into build that will modify ClCompile items.
Well I haven’t tried it but I’d start with something like this:

```
<Target Name="AppendMyGeneratedFilesToClCompile" DependsOnTargets="PreBuildEvent" Returns="@(ClCompile)" >
    <ItemGroup>
       <ClCompile Include="src\*.cpp" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Header files are meaningless for ClCompile target. You can include them into ClInclue but don't have to (from msbuild perspective you don't have to include them into msbuild project).