# Compile auto generated files without adding them to vcxproj

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been trying to find a solution to my question using several methods, however with no luck at all.

The problem I have is that I want my Visual Studio 2015 C++ project (.vcxproj) to **automatically** include **auto generated cpp files** (from prebuild event) in the compilation process.

So far the main suggestion I found is to add files to my project that match the names of the auto generated files. However, this is not a scalable/reliable solution because new files can be generated depending on the input, which means I have to manually add newly generated files.

I've tried using MSBUILD targets based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877110/vcxproj-does-not-build-generated-source-code-the-first-time), however that does not appear to work.

Is there any possible way to auto generate CPPs and have the project compile them without having to add them to the project?

Comment: If you use cmake (or similar). You can add `*.cpp`, but VS will only notice new files if a change is made to the cmake file (like putting a space in it).

Comment: Unfortunately not familiar or using CMAKE. Just VS on windows.